# What to do if my legacy device gets slower when Xposed Framework is enabled?

Tags: custom-roms, 7.0-nougat, xposed-framework, aosp, lagging

I'm using Xposed Framework 89 ver. on my Android 7.1.2 AOSP custom ROM: AOSiP which makes it slower but once I disable it my phone gets faster than the state of enabling. What can I do? Is there a lite version of it?

Comment: Is the device slower by your perception or is it only slower in some benchmark? Unfortunately the Xposed framework is designed to hook the central Dalvik-VM which is used (forked) by every app. Hence a little bit lower speed is excepted having Xposed installed. Usually with Xposed installed (without any modules) the device should not get much slower, however if you have a badly designed Xposed module this can be the cause.

Comment: It seems a little after a downgraded its version from 89ver to 88ver.